# My herkou discord.py bot is not starting and it is not getting any error

Tags: python, heroku, syntax-error, discord.py

Hi I am hosting my bot on heroku. My first bot was online but when I changed code it stopped going online and I am getting no errors in the logs.

You can check my code at
https://github.com/reyyan987/organic

Logs:

```
2021-02-27T13:29:06.299355+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python filename.py`
2021-02-27T13:29:07.003029+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-27T13:29:10.755961+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-27T13:29:10.819759+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: Open Github, and go to your repo and go to Pull Requests. I have submitted fixes for you, so just accept them then do `git pull` on your code.

Comment: Ok..............

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to run your bot `client.run`. I looked at your `procfile` and you're calling `filename.py` which is not running the bot. To solve your issue, just call your `setup` function at the bottom of `filename.py`. You also need to change `bot.run` to `client.run` since that's what you're using.

Comment: But in the previous not only bot.run was working but I will try

Comment: @Reyyan you did NOT call bot.run!

Comment: Oh I thought I did

Comment: Bro see I have bot.run(is.getenv('Token'))

Comment: @Reyyan you did not call setup(). Also you need `client.run` not `bot.run` https://github.com/reyyan987/organic/pull/1/files